# How do I create multipul Forms / .ui in qt?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I'm new to qt so this may be a basic question. I want to create multipul ui pages but I don't really know how to do it. I've gone `Add New -> C++ Class -> include QWidget`. Although this creates  new source and header files, it does not create and additional .ui file. I've tried building and running QMake but that hasn't helped. I've also tried adding temperature.ui to the forms section of the .pro files but that just gives me the
 `":-1: error: No rule to make target 'temperature.ui', needed by 'ui_temperature.h'.  Stop." error`. Any suggestions? Many thanks

Comment: `Add New... -> Qt -> Qt Designer Form Class`.

Comment: Qt is an [extremely well documented](http://doc.qt.io) framework, please read before posting.

Comment: It's also advised that you follow the one class: one form rule. Having multiple forms in one class only makes your code spaghetti code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing is a C++ Class and another thing is a Qt class. The first one has a *.cpp and a *.h and the second one has, in addition, a *.ui file which contains the ui made with Qt designer.

So that, you need to Add a Designer Form Class instead of a C++ class